# What's the difference between two implementations of RNN in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I find two kinds of implementations of RNN in tensorflow.

The first implementations is [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py) (from line 124 to 129). It uses a loop to define each step of input in RNN.

```
with tf.variable_scope("RNN"):
      for time_step in range(num_steps):
        if time_step > 0: tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
        (cell_output, state) = cell(inputs[:, time_step, :], state)
        outputs.append(cell_output)
        states.append(state)
```

The second implementation is [this](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.py) (from line 51 to 70). It doesn't use any loop to define each step of input in RNN.

```
def RNN(_X, _istate, _weights, _biases):

    # input shape: (batch_size, n_steps, n_input)
    _X = tf.transpose(_X, [1, 0, 2])  # permute n_steps and batch_size
    # Reshape to prepare input to hidden activation
    _X = tf.reshape(_X, [-1, n_input]) # (n_steps*batch_size, n_input)
    # Linear activation
    _X = tf.matmul(_X, _weights['hidden']) + _biases['hidden']

    # Define a lstm cell with tensorflow
    lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)
    # Split data because rnn cell needs a list of inputs for the RNN inner loop
    _X = tf.split(0, n_steps, _X) # n_steps * (batch_size, n_hidden)

    # Get lstm cell output
    outputs, states = rnn.rnn(lstm_cell, _X, initial_state=_istate)

    # Linear activation
    # Get inner loop last output
    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], _weights['out']) + _biases['out']
```

---

---

---

In the first implementation, I find **there is no weight matrix between input unit to hidden unit**, only define weight matrix between hidden unit to out put unit (from line 132 to 133)..

```
output = tf.reshape(tf.concat(1, outputs), [-1, size])
        softmax_w = tf.get_variable("softmax_w", [size, vocab_size])
        softmax_b = tf.get_variable("softmax_b", [vocab_size])
        logits = tf.matmul(output, softmax_w) + softmax_b
```

But in the second implementation, both of the weight matrices are defined (from line 42 to 47).

```
weights = {
    'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden])), # Hidden layer weights
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}
```

I wonder why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference I noticed is that the code in the [second implementation](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.py) uses tf.nn.rnn which takes list of inputs for each time step and generated the list of outputs for each time step.

(Inputs: A length T list of inputs, each a tensor of shape
      [batch_size, input_size].)

So, if you check the code in the second implementation on line 62 the input data is shaped into n_steps * (batch_size, n_hidden)

```
# Split data because rnn cell needs a list of inputs for the RNN inner loop
_X = tf.split(0, n_steps, _X) # n_steps * (batch_size, n_hidden)
```

In the [1st implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py) they are looping through the n_time_steps and providing the input and get the corresponding output and storing in the outputs list.

#### Code snippet from line 113 to 117

```
outputs = []
    state = self._initial_state
    with tf.variable_scope("RNN"):
      for time_step in range(num_steps):
        if time_step > 0: tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
        (cell_output, state) = cell(inputs[:, time_step, :], state)
        outputs.append(cell_output)
```

Coming to your second question:

If you carefully notice the way the inputs are being fed to the RNN in both the implementations.

In the first implementation the inputs are already of shape batch_size x num_steps (here num_steps is hidden size):

```
self._input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, num_steps])
```

Whereas in the second implementation the initial inputs are of shape (batch_size x n_steps x n_input). So a weight matrix is required to transform to the shape (n_steps x batch_size x hidden_size):

```
    # Input shape: (batch_size, n_steps, n_input)
    _X = tf.transpose(_X, [1, 0, 2])  # Permute n_steps and batch_size
    # Reshape to prepare input to hidden activation
    _X = tf.reshape(_X, [-1, n_input]) # (n_steps*batch_size, n_input)
    # Linear activation
    _X = tf.matmul(_X, _weights['hidden']) + _biases['hidden']
    # Split data because rnn cell needs a list of inputs for the RNN inner loop
    _X = tf.split(0, n_steps, _X) # n_steps * (batch_size, n_hidden)
```

I hope this is helpful...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One more question, In the Second implementation, I can use "sequence_length " parameter in rnn.rnn(), but in the first implementation I don't know where to use this parameter. Can you help me?

Comment: What the second implementation treats as "sequence_length" does the first implementation with "num_steps".

The link in your problem description is dead. Might you replace it with [this](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.py)?

Comment: @Rob Romijnders In the second implementation, you can use "sequence_length" to decide the length of sequence.